# Compile PHP using shared option and directory location

Tags: php, bash, unix

I cannot figure out the proper `./configure` options to use when giving the configure command if I would like to have something be shared (thus creating an .so extension) as well as stating a directory where required libraries are.

Example:

`--with-openssl=shared` will create a .so file

`--with-openssl=/home/username/local` will compile directly into the php build.

**How do I state both?** I see this nowhere in the php docs.

I am installing on a linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found it through trial and error as well as a few other posts of people going through different troubles that had their ./configure commands visible.

In my example case there are two flags you need:

```
--with-openssl=shared --with-openssl-dir=/home/username/local
```

In other instances there is no extension-name-dir flag, so you do comma separated values:

```
--with-cron=shared,/home/username/local
```

I could find no easy way to tell you which ones are which, but trial and error got me through these two that I needed. In the case of `GD` you actually need as many as four separate ones for the needed library support:

```
--with-gd=shared --with-jpeg-dir=/home/username/usr --with-png-dir=/home/username/usr --with-freetype-dir=/home/username/usr
```

Hope this helps someone else, I could find no other discussions about this issue (hard to believe there was no SO answers already).